# Why is paragraph before/after set to "auto" in an Outlook reply

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When I send an (html) email from Outlook it goes out with paragraph before & after settings to 0.
Replies come back with my text set with paragraph before / after set to "auto", which defaults to 12(?) points after - meaning my original text is spaced out (looks like double spaced).
Anybody know why & how to stop it happening?

Answer (score 0):

The issue usually occurs when you press Enter while creating HTML email and the message is double spaced when rendered in a browser.

To work around the issue, you can press Shift+Enter twice at the end of a paragrapg rather than pressing Enter twice when composing a new message. For more explanation, refer to this link:

[Messages are Double Spaced for the Recipient](https://www.slipstick.com/problems/messages-are-double-spaced/)